# invalid color name background in qgraph

Tags: r, visualization, igraph

I have been trying to use `qgraph` to generate the network graph. The code is as following

```
Gw <- qgraph(edgeList, diag = TRUE, labels = TRUE,legend.cex = 0.3, vsize = 1,edge.color=colorLabels,legend=TRUE,asize=1)
```

The figure can be generated, but the R command line gives the following error message. I do not know what does the `invalid color name 'background'` mean.

The `dput` result is shown as follows,

> dput(edgeList)
>   structure(c("1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "1", 
>   "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "16", 
>   "4", "5", "7", "1", "9", "10", "19", "20", "2", "16", "21", "3", 
>   "22", "5", "23", "8", "1", "20", "2", "13", "14", "17", "14", 
>   "1", "19", "14", "2", "21", "14", "24", "1", ":499.3", "nk Transfe", 
>   "de of tran", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", 
>   "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", 
>   "ine:4121", "ine:3257.4", "ine:75.2", "ine:75.2", "ine:11615.", 
>   "ine:10603", "ine:334.2", "ine:7256.8", "ine:7256.8", "ine:996.8", 
>   "ine:884.6", "ine:364.9", "ine:6360", "ine:5640.9", "ine:2729.7", 
>   "ine:5482.6", "ine:85", "ine:1474.9", "ine:700.8", "ine:2754.6", 
>   "ine:3257.4", "ine:3257.4", "ine:7307.8", "ine:18560.", "ine:85.1", 
>   "ine:364.8", ":700.1", ":5317", "l:4258.9", "l:4258.9", "l:1637.6", 
>   "l:1637.6", "l:46.4", "l:3938.5", "l:3938.5", "l:2800.4", "l:2715.1", 
>   "l:2715.1", "l:12708.2", "l:1042", ":499.3", "nk Transfe", "de of tran", 
>   "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", 
>   "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "up(non-US ", "ine:4121", 
>   "ine:3257.4", "ine:75.2", "ine:75.2", "ine:11615.", "ine:10603", 
>   "ine:334.2", "ine:7256.8", "ine:7256.8", "ine:996.8", "ine:884.6", 
>   "ine:364.9", "ine:6360", "ine:5640.9", "ine:2729.7", "ine:5482.6", 
>   "ine:85", "ine:1474.9", "ine:700.8", "ine:2754.6", "ine:3257.4", 
>   "ine:3257.4", "ine:7307.8", "ine:18560.", "ine:85.1", "ine:364.8", 
>   ":700.1", ":5317", "l:4258.9", "l:4258.9", "l:1637.6", "l:1637.6", 
>   "l:46.4", "l:3938.5", "l:3938.5", "l:2800.4", "l:2715.1", "l:2715.1", 
>   "l:12708.2", "l:1042", "25", "1", "1", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
>   "30", "31", "25", "32", "33", "4", "4", "3", "3", "5", "5", "7", 
>   "6", "6", "27", "28", "30", "25", "32", "33", "9", "8", "1", 
>   "1", "10", "12", "12", "16", "16", "16", "16", "8", "1", "3", 
>   "3", "7", "7", "25", "9", "9", "1", "10", "10", "14", "14"), .Dim = c(104L, 
>   2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("newsendId", "newtoId")))

The generated figure is as follows. I used the following command to generate it

```
Gw <- qgraph(edgeList, layout = "spring", diag = FALSE, labels = TRUE, cut = NULL, edge.color = "red",legend.cex = 0.5, vsize = 8)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your data. ideally using dput() to generate it?  We can then help answer this question and your later question.

Comment: Hi lawyeR, I have the data set in csv format. Could you tell me how to upload it here?

Comment: Assuming you have read in the data and assigned it to an R object (a data frame), type dput(name of data frame).  Then copy and paste the resulting output into your question above.  If it is too large, take a small portion of it, enough to reproduce your qgraph problem, and dput that bit.  We can then recreate your data set and tackle your problem.

Comment: Hi lawyeR, the dput result has been updated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi lawyeR, I also posted the generated figure, and do not know how to make it more informative. Currently, the label in some node are not clear because it has some content. i cannot make font too large, otherwise the nodes will be overlapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which nodes are problems?  With your data and code you can modify `label.cex.`  There are other variations of the arguments for the label and legend sizes[image].  Here is one version, with the color blue.

```
library(qgraph)
Gw <- qgraph(edgeList, layout = "spring", diag = FALSE, labels = TRUE, cut = NULL, edge.color = "red", legend.cex = 0.3, vsize = 4, label.cex = 0.3, label.color = "blue")
Gw
```

Comment: Hi lawyeR, thank you so much for your help. I have another question. In practice, each edge may come along with some text information, such as label, and explanation. How to add those things. In addition, after adding those edge-related information, the plot may be too busy, which is not visable, i.e., everything is overlapped. How to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: One idea is to shorten the text labels before you plot.  You can use a regex expression, such as to remove the "ine:" before many of them.