# Invalid color when using qgraph

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am trying to introduce a legend when using qgraph. My code is pretty simple

```
qgraph(plotmatrix, layout = "spring", legend=TRUE, label.color = "blue")
```

and the error message say

```
invalid color name 'background'
```

If I leave out the legend=TRUE, the error does not occure anymore. I have found the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451894/invalid-color-name-background-in-qgraph) where there was the same error message. However in the answer for the question the "legend=TRUE" was not used. Why do I get this error and hot do I introduce a legend properly?

Best

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the legend post-hoc.

If plotmatrix is a dataframe and you are using the NAMES column to color your graph by:

```
qgraph(plotmatrix, layout='spring', legend=FALSE, label.color='blue')

legend(locator(1), paste(levels(plotmatrix$NAMES)), col= 
as.numeric(levels(as.factor(unclass(plotmatrix$NAMES))))+1)
```

This colors the shapes of the points by the different levels of the NAMES of plotmatrix. `locator(1)` allows you to select, with a mouse click, where you would like to have the legend placed.

If you will post some sample data, I will edit this answer to better address your specific problem.